# Count Textfield lines in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I use "\n" to count the lines in a TextField and create a Container for each line (as shown in the image). Everything works fine. However, if I don't use "\n" and expand the text, it goes to the next line, but the Container doesn't get created accordingly. In the end, they all count as one line of Containers. What should I do to make it behave like "\n" when the width is filled and goes to the next line, creating a new Container?

[image]